# Ui Router Resolve - Cancel State Controller Load Afterwards?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Angular UI Router Question

When `$state.go("main.loadbalancer.readonly");` is activated in the `resolve` block, the `main.loadbalancer.vips` state controller `VipListCtrl` (the controller only) still loads after the resolve.

Since the state `main.loadbalancer.readonly` is activated, how can I keep make the controller `VipListCtrl` cancel and not load?

I tried using a promise and never having the promise resolve, but then the UI Router seems to stay sit at that resolve forever.

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer", ["ui.bootstrap", "ui.router"]).config(function($stateProvider) {
  return $stateProvider.state("main.loadbalancer", {
    url: "device/:id",
    views: {
      "content@": {
        templateUrl: "loadbalancer/loadbalancer.html",
        controller: "LoadBalancerCtrl"
      }
    }
  }).state("main.loadbalancer.vips", {
    resolve: {
        isDeviceReadOnly: function($state) {
        if (!$state.current.data['deviceId']) {
          $state.go("main.loadbalancer.readonly"); //THIS IS RAN...NEED CONTROLLER
                                                   //VipListCtrl TO NOT RUN AFTERWARDS
        }
      }
    },
    url: "/vips",
    templateUrl: "loadbalancer/vip-table.html",
    controller: "VipListCtrl"
  }).state("main.loadbalancer.nodes", {
    url: "/nodes",
    templateUrl: "loadbalancer/node-table.html",
    controller: "NodeListCtrl"
  }).state("main.loadbalancer.admin", {
    url: "/admin",
    templateUrl: "loadbalancer/admin.html",
    controller: "AdminCtrl"
  }).state("main.loadbalancer.readonly", {
    url: "/readonly",
    templateUrl: "loadbalancer/readonly.html",
    controller: "ReadonlyCtrl"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 resolve: {
        isDeviceReadOnly: function($state, $q, $timeout) {
        if (!$state.current.data['deviceId']) {
          $timeout(function() { $state.go("main.loadbalancer.readonly"); });
          return $q.reject("rejection message"); // <-- Gotta reject your resolve
        }
      }
    },
```

plunk which demonstrates $q.reject cancelling the transition: http://plnkr.co/edit/njJtyVbKD4rDY3OckAF6?p=preview

Comment: I am not convinced that $q.reject() cancels the controller from running. I think it just makes a hung state for UI Router where the resolve is never complete and waits.

Comment: It does. What the above was missing was wrapping in $timeout: http://plnkr.co/edit/njJtyVbKD4rDY3OckAF6?p=preview  Edited answer.